# Unable to restart apache

Tags: apache

I have dedicated server:

- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
- Red Hat 4.4.4-13 OS with Webuzo CPanel
- httpd-tools-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64
- httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64
- httpd-devel-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64

Few hours ago my server has worked normally, and after my last modification of httpd.conf there is no force to make apache working. Before I changed httpd.conf I've made a backup, and now restored it but i'm still unable to restart apache. I really don't have a clue what could possibly go wrong having in mind that i didn't do anything abnormal, i've just changed one line in http.conf.

`service httpd start` gives me

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

`netstat -lp | grep ":80"` doesn't return anything.

As i wrote above, i have Webuzo, and when i do `service webuzo restart` i get:

```
Stopping nginx: Done...
Stopping php-fpm: Done...
Starting nginx: Done...
Starting php-fpm: Done...
```

So it seems that i have nginx installed on my server, and i assume that nginx is using that adresses (port 80, which is why apache is protesting, i suppose..)

And one last thing - there are no log files in apache/log folder so i'm completely blind to find out this freaking error..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to check for the service running on port 80.

```
Root > yum install lsof

Root > lsof -i :80
```

Kill the processes running on the port and restart the Apache service.

Webuzo compiles the Apache package at `/usr/local/apps/apache` and does not use the default yum installation.

Logs can be found at  `/usr/local/apps/apache/logs/`

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: This lsof query was pretty useful to find out that all the httpd processes were listed as IPv6 (for both port 80 and 443 in my case). We are not yet on IPV6, and to force it to be IPV4, the /etc/httpd/httpd.conf Listen directive needed to be changed from Listen 80 to Listen 0.0.0.0:80 (same for 443). This was related, but also a httpd bug seemed to be in the way with this same symptom. See http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7647 (BTW, updating to CentOS 6.6 got rid of the problem).